# Como forçar a limpeza de cache nos navegadores dos meus visitantes

Tags: css, apache, cache

Eu costumo atualizar bastante a folha de estilos do meu site (CSS).
O que acontece é que meus visitantes não veem diferenças.
Existe algum script ou algo do tipo que force a limpeza?
Exemplo: No próximo acesso o cache será limpado.
Algum cookie que faça com que o cache dure somente 3 dias por exemplo.
Simplesmente não sei o que fazer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para Apache, podes fazer uso do ficheiro `htaccess` com as directivas para control de cache que informam os navegadores sobre a altura em que o mesmo deverá fazer download de uma nova versão de cada ficheiro.

### Alguns exemplos:

```rd
Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset ETag

# 1 Ano (limitado a ficheiro media)
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|mp3|mp4)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2010 20:00:00 GMT"
Header unset Last-Modified
</FilesMatch>

# 2 Horas (limitado a ficheiro conteúdos)
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|xml|txt|xsl)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

# Em cache para sempre (scripts e folhas de estilo)
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2010 20:00:00 GMT"
Header unset Last-Modified
</FilesMatch>
```

### Exemplo de cache em ficheiros CSS limitada a 3 dias

1. Criar ficheiro `.htaccess` na raiz da pasta que contém os ficheiros alvo;
2. Escrever dentro do ficheiro o controlo de cache adequado;
3. Indicar as extensões de ficheiros afectas ao controlo a ser aplicado:

   ```rd
   # extensões separadas por um |
   <FilesMatch "\.(css)$">
   ```
4. Indicar a duração da cache para que o servidor diga ao navegador que determinado ficheiro só é válido durante o tempo indicado, findo o qual deverá ser recolhido outro:

   ```rd
   # max-age = XX segundos
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=259200, must-revalidate"
   ```

O resultado do ficheiro a utilizar fica:

```rd
Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset ETag

# 3 Dias
<FilesMatch "\.(css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=259200, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Excelente! @Zuul

Comment: Vou utilizar desta forma:
`# 5 Dias
# O cabeçalho "pragma" é para compatibilidade com o IE
<FilesMatch "(css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=432000, public, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "max-age=432000, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>`

Answer (score 3):

Você pode em PHP modificar o cache da página:

```
<?php
//Prevent page caching
 header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
 header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

Ou você pode usar um TIME no link do css, exemplo :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="estilo.css?<?php echo time(); ?>" />
```

Comment: Ou eu não soube explicar ou você não entendeu bem o que eu quero.
O que quero é limpar o cache das folhas de estilos.
Vamos supor, quero que o cache dure somente 3 dias, depois disso quando a pessoa acessar novamente ele irá forçar a limpeza do cache, pois eu faço as alterações e os visitantes não veem, pois está cacheada.

Comment: editei a resposta...é isso ?

Comment: Não é bem isso. rs
Se eu fizer isso, o site vai ficar com uma lerdesa muito grande.

Comment: coloquei outra opção usando php!!!