# Carregar CSS no PHP instantaneamente

Tags: php, css

Reparei que conforme edito o CSS nas páginas PHP, os estilos demoram muito para entrar (alguns scripts e códigos HTML também), sendo preciso às vezes desabilitar o EasyPHP e habilitar de novo. Às vezes o modo anônimo nos navegadores também funciona, mas nem sempre.

Como eu poderia fazer pra que os estilos carregassem assim que eu desse F5? Ou eu vou precisar conviver com a demora?

Comment: [Forçar atualização de arquivo javascript sem desativar cache](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68382/5878)

Comment: [Como forçar a limpeza de cache nos navegadores dos meus visitantes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21724/5878)